# Why is my UNION twice as fast as my UNION ALL? (SQL Server ~140k records)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, union

I am asking this question purely out of interest since I can't for the life of me explain why this is happening, especially to this degree. As far as I knew, combining result sets without checking for duplicates would always be as fast as / (usually) faster than with checking!

Basically, there are two views returning ~78.000 and ~63.000 records in ~7 seconds respectively. They have the same super long query, just reading from different tables (same indexes).

### Combining the views

```
SELECT * FROM v1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM v2
```

This results in **141.167 rows** after ~**14 seconds**. Twice the data, twice the time. Makes sense.

Now, purely out of interest I ran the same query but instead of a `UNION ALL` I just used a `UNION` on the result sets.

To my surprise, I got the same **141.167 rows** in a whopping ~**7 seconds**!

The records returned by the views are already unique, so I would generally use `UNION ALL`, but this is twice as fast when I eliminate duplicates that don't exist, so what gives?

### Execution plans

The execution plans are the same except for the last few steps since, obviously, they are different. I'm not that well versed in understanding them (especially being so long), but I don't want to leak any sensitive data here:

[image: final steps]

[image: the execution plan properties]

I was going to upload the execution plans to pastetheplan but they're both >2MB so it wouldn't let me. Instead, here are google drive links for the cleaned version (I only replaced table names):

[UNION.sqlplan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f8RT8rGb_KqTufHYbdSoSuC2HRuEFbSE/view?usp=sharing)

[UNION_ALL.sqlplan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DpZKENn6pJ_lZQvQi36DM9mqVerzPl1R/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: (Bad) query cache? What happens if you force the data engine to recompile the query plans when you run them both?

Comment: Not possible to say based on the limited data provided. The execution plans are parallel. Maybe the faster one ran at higher degree of parallelism - or by chance ended up with a better execution plan. Or had less physical reads and associated IO waits or less for some transient wait type

Comment: Maybe you ran the `UNION` query right after the `UNION ALL`query, so data was still in some cache and didn't have to be read from disk?

Comment: Upload the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.

Comment: Yep, it's something about the cache then. After recompiling the view accessing the two views they now both went up to about 17s of execution time multiple times in a row. I suppose I would need to recompile the sub-views too but I can't do that.

What does this mean for me in practice? Which one should my view be using in the future?

I'll clean up my query plan and post it soon @DanGuzman

Comment: Even if they run about the same time now, keep in mind that `UNION` has more work to do than `UNION ALL`, because it must look for duplicates and remove them. So, only use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, when you really need the DBMS to remove possible duplicates.